# One specific turtle must stop after visiting specific point

Tags: move, target

I'm studying NetLogo and have a question about some specific point that I could not find answer. Overall, I am trying to write a program that has these features:

- Two country flag
- First country flag will move **1.B, 2.C, 3.D** from  **A** city (stop at D)
- Second country flag will move **E** from **G** city
- Second country flag will move **G** from **D** city
- While first country moving these city. The flag drop army (*For instance Starting 100k soldier at A . It will 90k at B and C 80k etc.*)
- When they meet at **D** city at same time first country flag lose all soldier.
- I want to plot the number of soldiers depending on time. Time / Number PLOT
- I need only setup and go buttons if it possible.

I am starting with just moving the first flag, based on a program that is included in the library.

In this part I am trying to create different cities with different locations.

```
to setup   
  clear-all   
  set-default-shape houses "house" 

  ;; CREATE-ORDERED-<BREEDS> distributes the houses evenly  
  create-ordered-houses number-of-city
    [ setxy 5 4 ] ;; B
  create-ordered-houses number-of-city
    [ setxy 1 4 ] ;; C
  create-ordered-houses number-of-city
    [ setxy 11 6 ] ;; D
```

In this part I'm trying to create flags

```
create-people number-of-people [
  setxy -8 10 ;; A city for first flag
  set target one-of houses
  facexy 5 4
```

This is the part I'm trying to understand (Copied from library ). It's about movement of the first flag.

```
ask people [
  ;; if at target, choose a new random target
  if distance target = 0
    [ set target one-of houses
      face target ]
  ;; move towards target.  once the distance is less than 1,
  ;; use move-to to land exactly on the target.
  ifelse distance target < 1
    [ move-to target ]
    [ fd 1 ]
```

When I run with this code, the first flag moves to the wrong place. I explain my problem in this picture.

Movement of my first flag
[image: img]

Comment: Need heeaaalp! any idea ?

Comment: Please use the {} brackets that are called 'code sample' for sections of code, not the quote. I have edited to fix the code sample and other problems of clarity.

Comment: Thank you JenB . Sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adapting code that only has one possible target. In that code, it is fine to use `one-of` to select the target because there's only one choice. In your adaptation, however, there's more than one choice. So when you create the flag in your second block of code...

```
set target one-of houses
facexy 5 4
```

... you are choosing a random target from any of the four houses, and then facing house B (which is at 5 4). Let's say the random choice (`one-of`) picked house C. You flag moves towards B because you told it to face (5 4) and then move forward, but your test for whether it gets close is distance to the target (that is, distance to C if that's the one that was randomly chosen).

Try changing that piece of code to:

```
set target one-of other houses
facexy target
```

This code will make the flag go to a randomly selected house that is not the house they are currently at. Since you actually want them to go in a particular order, you will have to do something like give each house a name (that is, create a `houses-own` attribute to identify each one) and then have the flag do something like `set target house with [ name = 'B' ]`. However, make this change after you have everything about moving working. Your general approach of adding a little bit at a time is correct - get it moving to any target and then worry about moving to the correct target.